# Lognormal Distribution as Maximum Entropy Probability Distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, lognormal-distribution, entropy, maximum-entropy

According to the wikipedia article on the lognormal distribution, the lognormal distribution is "the maximum entropy probability distribution for a random variate $X$ for which the mean and variance of $\log(X)$  is fixed".

Is there a not too complicated account of what this means and how this is derived?

Comment: You didn't correctly copy the sentence from wikipedia. Insert a $\ln(X)$ between 'is' and 'fixed'.

Comment: I've inserted a $\ln(X)$ before "is fixed", thanks for the hint.

Comment: The Wikipedia article references a [clear paper](http://www.wise.xmu.edu.cn/Master/Download/..%5C..%5CUploadFiles%5Cpaper-masterdownload%5C2009519932327055475115776.pdf) by Park & Bera in which the result is derived.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the $\log(X)\sim \mbox{Normal}(\mu,\sigma^2)$, therefore they are actually making a claim regarding the normal distribution. For a normal distribution we have that

> The normal distribution Normal$(\mu,\sigma^2)$ has maximum entropy among all real-valued distributions with specified mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$.

Check this wikipedia entry for more details (including the proof of this result): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_entropy_probability_distribution#Given_mean_and_standard_deviation:_the_normal_distribution

Comment: Thanks a lot for this hint, it was quite helpful. Also I had seen the paper linked on wikipedia, it did not look trivial though. I have one question regarding this property: We do have biological data where the data is a set of measured lenghts, and these lengths have a lognormal distribution. Knowing that in biology cost-minimization is crucial, I wondered if the Maximum Entropy property could be linked to cost-reduction? Sorry if the question is vague! P.

Comment: This is a new question, you should then ask it as a new question, not just in comments!